# I can't search for messages written by myself

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, search

I don't know if it's because I recently changed my name, or whether my current name is too short, but I can't search for messages by either my old name or new name:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: This is probably because people who changes names are, well,  [you know](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11068145#11068145)

Comment: What is your old name?

Comment: Just type your userid (11935) into the box. It's probably an issue with capping the number of user result and not prioritizing exact matches; I'll look at that later.

Comment: @balpha While you're at it, can you fix mobile chat plz?

Comment: [here you go](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=11935&q=imgur) :)

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: I read the title as, "I can't do this by myself" :-)

Comment: [@balpha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22mobile+chat%22&user=&room=35)